# here the finale result is 1.0 for any input image how can i fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, keras

```
# detecting artery and vein
mask2 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/org.tiff')
imgseg =  cv2.imread('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/inverted.tiff')
_,mask2,_ = cv2.split(mask2)
plt.imshow(mask2)
plt.show()

print(mask.shape,mask2.shape)
count = 0
intensity = 0
for x in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for y in range(mask.shape[1]):       
        if mask[x][y] and mask2[x][y]:
            intensity = intensity + imgseg[x][y][1]
            count = count + 1
print('intensity sum {}'.format(intensity))       
intensitymean = int(intensity/count)
print('intensity mean {} and count {}'.format(intensitymean,count))
artery = mask.copy()
vein = mask.copy()
plt.imshow(artery) 
plt.show()
plt.imshow(vein)
plt.show()
for x in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for y in range(mask.shape[1]):
        if mask[x][y] and mask2[x][y]:
            if imgseg[x][y][1] >= intensitymean-15:
                artery[x][y] = 0
            else:
                vein[x][y] = 0
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/artery11111.tiff',artery)
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/vein11111.tiff',vein)            
plt.imshow(artery)     
plt.show()

plt.imshow(vein)
plt.show()
# invert
artery = 255 - artery
vein = 255 - vein
plt.imshow(artery)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(vein)
plt.show()
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/artery.tiff',artery)
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/vein.tiff',vein)
# distance transform
print(artery.dtype)
arteryDist = cv2.distanceTransform(artery,cv2.DIST_L1, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
veinDist = cv2.distanceTransform(vein,cv2.DIST_L1, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
print(len(arteryDist))
print(len(veinDist))
plt.imshow(arteryDist)
plt.show()
plt.imshow(veinDist)
plt.show()
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/veinDist.tiff', veinDist)
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/arteryDist.tiff', arteryDist)
# thinning 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(5,5))
size = np.size(arteryDist)
arteryskel = np.zeros(arteryDist.shape,np.uint8)
done = False
while not done:
    eroded = cv2.erode(arteryDist, kernel)
    print('Erosion completed')
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded, kernel)
    print('Dilation completed')
    temp = cv2.subtract(arteryDist, temp)
    print('Subtraction completed')
    arteryskel = temp.copy()
    arteryDist = eroded.copy()
 
    if cv2.countNonZero(arteryDist) == 0:
        done = True
        print('Thinning process completed')
    else:
        print('Thinning process in progress')
print(done)
plt.imshow(arteryskel)
plt.show()
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/arteryskel1.tiff',arteryskel)
print('Output image saved')
veinskel = np.zeros(veinDist.shape,np.uint8)
done = False
while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(veinDist,kernel)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,kernel)
    temp = cv2.subtract(veinDist,temp)
    veinskel = temp.copy()
    veinDist = eroded.copy()
 
    if cv2.countNonZero(arteryDist) == 0:  
        done = True

print(done)
plt.imshow(veinskel)
plt.show()
cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/soltan/Desktop/project jupyter/DB/veinskel.tiff',veinskel)
venuole = []
arteriole = []
for x in range(veinskel.shape[0]):
    for y in range(veinskel.shape[1]):
        if veinskel[x][y] > 0:
            venuole.append(abs(veinskel[x][y]))
        if arteryskel[x][y] > 0:
            arteriole.append(abs(arteryskel[x][y]))

venuole = sorted(venuole)
arteriole = sorted(arteriole)
print("venuole=",venuole)
print("arteriole",arteriole)
lenven = len(venuole)
print('length of lenven {} {} {}'.format(lenven,lenven//2,lenven//2-1))
if lenven%2 == 1:
    Wa = venuole[lenven//2]
    if lenven//2 == 0:
        Wb = venuole[0]
    else:
        Wb = venuole[lenven//2 - 1]
else:
    Wa = (venuole[lenven//2 - 1] + venuole[lenven//2])// 2
    Wb = venuole[lenven//2 - 1]
print(Wa,Wb)
CRVE = sqrt(0.72*(Wa**2) + 0.91*(Wb**2) + 450.02)
print("CRVE=",CRVE)
lenart = len(arteriole)
print('length of lenart {} {} {}'.format(lenart,lenart//2,lenart//2-1))
if lenart%2 == 1:
    Wa = arteriole[lenart//2]
    if lenart//2 == 0:
        Wb = arteriole[0]
    else:
        Wb = arteriole[lenart//2 - 1]
else:
    Wa = (arteriole[lenart//2 - 1] + arteriole[lenart//2])// 2
    Wb = arteriole[lenart//2 - 1]

print(Wa,Wb)
CRAE = sqrt(0.8*(Wa**2) + 1.01*(Wb**2) - 0.22*Wa*Wb-10.73)
print("CRAE=",CRAE)
if len(venuole) == 0 or len(arteriole) == 0:
    print("Il n'y a pas de vaisseaux dans l'image")
else:
    artervenratio = CRAE/CRVE
print('arteriovenous ratio {}'.format(artervenratio))
```

the "veinskel" and "arteryskel" images are created using a "thinning" process, which reduces the thickness of the blood vessels in the "veinDist" and "arteryDist" images.

In the thinning process, a series of erosion and dilation operations are performed on the original image using a 5x5 size cross-shaped kernel. The resulting image is then subtracted from the original image to obtain the eroded image.

The process repeats until the eroded image no longer contains any non-zero pixels, which means the image has been sharpened enough. The resulting "veinskel" and "arteryskel" images contain only binary values of 0 and 1, where 1 represents blood vessel pixels.

Then, the lists "venuole" and "arteriole" are filled from the non-zero pixel values in these images, noting that the input image is not binary the avr is value greter then 0 (flotant)